# Check if data from database is up to date

Tags: postgresql

I'm storing some data from database, and want to check if that data is up-to-date from the database version. What is the best way to do this?

My ideas:

- Getting checksum from the table and comparing with last update
  checksum (must be an overkill)
- Getting table modification date and
  comparing with current data update time

Answer (score 2):

Just keep "last updated/last stored" as timestamp value. Easy to do even on a record level (i.e. for each record, and not for whole table).

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions:

CREATE trigger after update / insert / delete to  update log table.

If you use procedures to CRUD add `UPDATE log SET tablex_modified = NOW();`

If you do only `INSERTs` and you use sequences in primary key you can check those values with `current_val('seq_x')`

'pg_stats' may have something useful